# OpenCV installition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I installed OpenCV latest version to Ubuntu 14.04. 
I'm following the instructions give at: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

When I run the following code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg') 
cv2.imshow('Frame', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
(Frame:4833): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.
```

Comment: Try updating your OpenGL version. Are you on a PC without a GPU?

Comment: I'm using a computer without GPU, but don't you think that it should work without GPU?

Comment: Computers without GPU tend to use CPU graphic processing and this is run with very old and crude version of OpenGL. I'd assume that openCV is accounting for this scenarion, but there are incountable things that you can not do with the old OpenGL versions (such as non-square textures, etc). This is not necesarily the reason of your problem, but it may

Comment: @AnderBiguri ,I checked that computer has a intel GPU card.
description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

Comment: Test the computer for OpenGl version.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, when i try to get OpenGL version i'm getting this error do you have any idea? Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".                      And i'm using that command to get OpenGL infor glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"

Comment: I have no idea. Try to make sure openGL in isntalled and running on your PC.

Comment: You can compile OpenCV without OpenGL support.  Modify the CMake configuration of your setup to exclude the inclusion of OpenGL in your version of OpenCV.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV?

Comment: The website suggests multiple options

Comment: I called this command for cmake  cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..